# Initializing entry to 0 in tinker

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a set of entry widget and I am able to set the value and print on the command. Now I would like to initialize fields to 0 when I hit reset button and show all 0 on the command.. How can I achieve this?

```py
    import tkinter as tk

    fields = 'test','test1', 'test2', 'test4'

    def fetch(entries):
        for entry in entries:
            field = entry[0]
            text  = entry[1].get()
            print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) 

    def makeform(root, fields):
        entries = []
        for field in fields:
            row = tk.Frame(root)
            lab = tk.Label(row, width=20, text=field, anchor='w')
            ent = tk.Entry(row)
            row.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X, padx=10, pady=10)
            lab.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
            ent.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X)
            entries.append((field, ent))
        return entries

    def clearTextInput():
        entries.delete(0,"end")

    def reset():
    for tk_var in fields:
        tk_var.set(0.0)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        root = tk.Tk()
        ents = makeform(root, fields)
        root.bind('event', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e))) 

        b1 = tk.Button(root, text='Set', command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
        b1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        b2 = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=root.quit)
        b2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can solve it yourself easily, refer document for [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Comment: ***`entries.delete(0,"end")`***: `entries` is of type `list` not `Entry`. You have to loop all items in the list.

Comment: I revised it but i still get an error saying str object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: [Edit] your question to show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```
def reset():
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, "a default value")
```

then in button: command=reset

Answer (score -1):

def clear():
    ent.delete(0,END)